# In topology, any relationship on boundary like $Bd(A\cap B)$ and $Bd(A) \cap Bd(B)$?

Tags: general-topology

Given a topological space $(X,\mu)$, let $Bd(S)$ denote the boundary of subset $S\subseteq X$.

Is there any relationship between $Bd(A\cap B)$ and $Bd(A)\cap Bd(B)$ for arbitrary subsets $A,B\subseteq X$?

This question came to my mind when I did the following assignment from topology lecture:

> Prove $Bd(A\cup B)\subset Bd(A)\cup Bd(B)$.

After completing the proof I thought "how about the intersection?"

It would be great to consider the above in infinite sets and finite sets, if the results are different.

Comment: What is $Bd(A)$? Bounded functions from $A$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Sorry for insufficient explanation. $Bd(A)$ is the boundary of subset $A$. $A$ and $B$ are subsets of a topological scape $(X,\mu)$ .

Comment: Have you thought about how you would prove this? Have you thought about counterexamples?

Comment: @AlexR I don't think it's true that $\partial A\cap\partial B\subset\partial(A\cap B)$.  What if $A=\mathbb Q$ and $B=\mathbb Q^c$?

Comment: @GregoryGrant Bollocks. I was only imagining well-behaved sets. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @AlexR I think you might be right thought that $\partial A\cap\partial B\subset\partial(A\cup B)$.  I can't think of a counter-example.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Yes, but that's not what the question is asking for anyway. You could answer that there is no inherent relation because both cases, $\subset$ and $\supset$ are possible.

Comment: @AlexR Good idea, I went ahead and posted such an answer.  Just need a counter-example for each containment.

Comment: @GregoryGrant If that - $\partial A\cap \partial B \subset \partial (A\cup B)$ - would hold for all $A,B$, then since $\partial A = \partial (X-A)$, we'd have $$\partial A \cap \partial B = \partial (X-A) \cap \partial (X-B) \subset \partial \bigl((X-A) \cup (X-B)\bigr) = \partial \bigl(X - (A\cap B)\bigr) = \partial (A\cap B),$$ but we know that's not true in general. $\partial (A\cap B) \subset \partial A\cup \partial B$ is the best we can get, pretty much, I think.

Comment: Maybe if $A$ and $B$ are closed, we can get a little more...

Comment: The conjecture is false even for well-behaved sets. Let $A$ be a disc and $B$ be its complement.

Answer (score 4):

There's no containment relationship between $\partial A\cap\partial B$ and $\partial(A\cap B)$ that always holds.  To prove that we need two counter-examples.

If $A=\mathbb Q$ and $B=\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$, then $\partial A=\partial B=\mathbb R$.  But $\partial (A\cap B)=\emptyset$.  So it's not true in general that $\partial A\cap\partial B\subset\partial(A\cap B)$.

On the other hand if $A=\mathbb Q$ and $B=\mathbb R$, then $\partial A=\mathbb R$.  And $A\cap B=A$.  So $\partial (A\cap B)=\mathbb R$.  But $\partial B=\emptyset$.  So $\partial A\cap\partial B=\emptyset$.  Thus it's not true in general that $\partial A\cap\partial B\supset\partial(A\cap B)$.

So there is no general statement you can make.  But maybe you can put some restrictions on $A$ and $B$ so that something is true in some special case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind answer.

I understand well about it. How about the universal set $X$ is finite set?

Comment: @Pengin You're welcome.  Please hit the check mark if you accept the answer.  If $X$ is finite then all boundaries are empty right?

Comment: @GragoryGrant I don't think _ If X is finite then all boundaries are empty_. For instance, let $X=\{ a,b,c,d \}$ and take $O=\{ \emptyset,\{ c\} ,\{ a,c\} ,\{ b,c\} ,\{ a,b,c\} ,X\} $ as a topology over $X$. For a subset $A=\{ a,b\}$, $bd(A)=\{ a,b,c\}$ because the interior is $\emptyset$, the closure is  $\{ a,b,c\}$, thus $bd(A)=\{ a,b,c\} - \{ \emptyset \}$.

Answer (score 1):

If we take $Bd(A) = \overline{A}\backslash A^{\circ}$, then $$Bd(\mathbb Q) = \mathbb R,$$ and $$Bd(\mathbb R \backslash \mathbb Q) = \mathbb R,$$ so that $$Bd(\mathbb Q)\cap Bd(\mathbb R \backslash \mathbb Q) = \mathbb R.$$

But $Bd(\mathbb R \backslash \mathbb Q \cap \mathbb Q) = Bd(\emptyset) = \emptyset$.

So $Bd(\mathbb R \backslash \mathbb Q \cap \mathbb Q) \subset Bd(\mathbb Q)\cap Bd(\mathbb R \backslash \mathbb Q)$.

Now use $A = (0,1)$ and $B=(1/2,2)$ to see that this relation fails in general.

In fact, $Bd(A\cap B) = \{1/2,1\}$ whereas $Bd(A)\cap Bd(B) = \emptyset$.

So no simple relation exists in general.